# How to validate HTML input using Java/Nuxeo

Tags: java, html, validation, nuxeo

Are HTML parsers the only way to validate whether input is valid HTML? I am using Java and Nuxeo.

Comment: some regex , but not perfect

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, so regex is the wrong answer to HTML validation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any java libraries for validating user supplied HTML, on the server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336353/are-there-any-java-libraries-for-validating-user-supplied-html-on-the-server-si)

Answer (score 0):

If your source is in XHTML format, you might be able to use XHTML schema to validate using Xerces or any standard dom parser. Isn't this the way the browsers validate the XHTML document?